# how to change imagebox with a button | c# windows forms

Tags: c#, image, button

I would want to change an image from first to second using a button. The first image should be always loaded when starting my form, after pressing the button the image swaps with the second and then vice versa. How could i do that? 
 The image is loaded by an imgbox and it has no code. All of the images are stored in a folder called resources. Form1.cs code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using WMPLib;

namespace WindowsFormsApp4
{


    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        WindowsMediaPlayer player = new WindowsMediaPlayer();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            player.URL = "tada.mp3";
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            player.controls.play();
        }

        private void changebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_HelpButtonClicked(Object sender, CancelEventArgs e)

        {

            MessageBox.Show("PZP - Przeglądarka zdjęć P0150Na", "Informacje", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }
}
```

Sincerely 
 p0150n

Comment: Did you add a click handler for your button yet?

Comment: Yes, i did. I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Please provide your code snippet.

Comment: `private void changebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            

        }`

The rest of things in namespace is code for clicking help button and playing a sound when launched. There are no errors or warnings.

Comment: please include your event handler code in your post by clicking on edit... We will be interested in the logic that you're using for changing the images...your code in your comment doesn't actually do anything... so we'll need to see the rest of your code. ie: how you are displaying the default image and where the others are stored.

Comment: I don't know how to do it, that's why i asked. I didn't code the change ability for the images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an array of all posible images. Add a variable to store currently loaded image index in this array. And on buttonClick event, change the currently loaded image index, and load the image to picturebox. With this idea, you may have more than 2 images. Something like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string[] images = new string[] { "image1.bmp", "image2.bmp", "image3.bmp" };
    int currentImageIndex = 0;

    ...
    private void changebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        currentImageIndex++;
        if (currentImageIndex == images.Length)
            currentImageIndex = 0;

        pictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(images[currentImageIndex]));
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I get two CS0825 errors because of the vars. Are you sure i should put that code in that place?

Comment: I changed it to string[] and int.

Comment: Now i get a CS0029 error that i can't convert a string to System.Drawing.Image.

Comment: See my new edits. I wrote the code in notepad, so there might be some mistakes.

Comment: I launched the form without the second ) as i get two errors saying that } and ; were expected. The button doesn't do anything just like without the code you wrote for me.

Comment: is this event (changebutton_Click) is called at all? Have you tried to add a breakpoint and debug it?

Answer (score 0):

VDN, when i coded `changebutton.Click += new EventHandler(changebutton_Click);` in `public Form1()` when i clicked the button (that is named "changebutton", if it matters) my IDE showed me an unhandled exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: „nerf.png”. That file is the second image i want to show.